# Tag synonym request: [mtg-dotp-2012] and [magic-2012]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

So Wizards of the Coast, not satisfied with having a really long company name, has taken to making video games with excessively long names, too. Last year, they released *Magic: The Gathering: Duels of the Planeswalkers* and [mtg-duels-of-planeswalker](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-duels-of-planeswalker) was created as a way to fit most of the title into the 25-character tag limit.

Not to be outdone, they released a follow-up this year, *Magic: The Gathering: Duels of the Planeswalkers 2012*, a functionally different game that really does need a separate tag. Unfortunately, [duels-of-planeswalker](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duels-of-planeswalker) is 25 characters, so the "2012" can't be tacked on.

I [asked a question about it](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/24807/3389) a few days ago, and the tag [mtg-dotp-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-dotp-2012) was created as a way to distinguish it from the earlier game, with the justification that "DotP" is sometimes used to refer to the series.

But the plot thickens: in trophy lists and in reviews, *Magic 2012* is used to shorten the name of the game, and quick Google searches seem to indicate it has some good SEO (especially since Wizards of the Coast is *also* releasing the *Magic 2012* core set for the physical card game at the same time).

[image: Trophy List]

So I humbly request we use [magic-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-2012) and make [mtg-dotp-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-dotp-2012) a synonym of it.

*P.S. There's also a case to be made that [duels-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/duels-2012) should be a synonym too: WotC has used that shortened form in its [FAQ for the game](http://www.wizards.com/magic/digital/DuelsOfThePlaneswalkers.aspx?x=mtg/digital/dotp/faq) for example. But "Duels" is such a generic name, and I doubt many people would search for the game using it.*

Comment: I would see tagging as [magic-2012] being misleading, as it wouldn't be talking about the Core Set and the site doesn't handle the card version of the game. I could see this being a valid tag on the Board and Card games site, but for here, I don't think I agree.

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Wizards of the Coast is the one choosing to associate the game with the core set. I've added a screenshot of the Trophy List in the XMB to show what I'm referring to: *Magic 2012* in the list refers to *Magic: The Gathering: Duels of the Planeswalkers 2012*

Comment: Ah, I stand corrected. :) Interesting decision, though still somewhat confusing, on their part. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just hope that with the i18n efforts caused by German and Japanese, the tagging system will relax a little bit. :/