# Tag rename request: [mtg-online] → [magic-online]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

There are two questions tagged [mtg-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-online); however, [the name of the game is *Magic Online*](http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Digital/MagicOnline.aspx), not *Magic: The Gathering Online* (the "The Gathering" part is just part of the logo in this case: it is not referred to as such in copy).

This should be renamed to [magic-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-online). It probably makes sense, after the rename, to add a synonym to it for [mtg-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-online) and [mtgo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtgo) (its colloquial name).

This solution would also have the side effect of matching [our usage of *Magic 2012/2013*](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2437/3389), standardizing *Magic*-related games on `magic-*` for the main tag and `mtg-*` as a synonym.

#### Google ranking

[Rilgon Arcsinh brings up](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5193/3389) the valid concern of whether the change could adversely affect our Google ranking for those who might be searching under other forms of the game name (including, ostensibly, "MTG Online"). This change will have very little (if any) effect on this:

- Google [silently auto-expands "mtg" to "magic the gathering" in searches](http://www.google.com/search?q=mtg%20online), and searching for "mtg online" alone is dominated with results for "magic online".
- Because of Google's silent expansion of Magic-related terms to "magic the gathering", we already rank first even when we don't use one of the colloquial forms: for example, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/79012/3389) comes up as the first result for "[mtgo effective card collection](http://google.com/search?q=mtgo%20effective%20card%20collection)" even though "MTGO" doesn't appear anywhere in the question.

That is to say, Google is smart enough to understand you mean *Magic Online* when you try to search on "mtgo", "magic online", "mtg online", or "magic the gathering online", so it's unnecessary to explicitly mention the colloquial forms in our questions or tags. The synonyms are then just needed in case someone starts typing "mtg" instead of "magic" when they go to add tags.

Answer (score 3):

My only concern regarding this would be that most players - and, presumably, those that would be googling for questions related to it - usually refer to it as MTG Online (or MTGO). That said, if a synonym can keep that sort of symbolic link where questions can be found online through "mtg online $QUERY", then all for it.

Comment: "MTGO" sure, but [citation needed] on "most players" calling it "MTG Online": it's referred to as either Magic Online or MTGO colloquially, with the former being its official name. There's no risk of Googlers getting confused, either: besides us only having two questions (so we don't rank on "mtg online" anyway), Google [automatically replaces "mtg online" with "magic: the gathering online" in searches](http://www.google.com/search?q=mtg+online), which is then dominated results for "magic online".

Comment: Oh I really can't cite it, it's wholly subjective, founded off of following a few MTG pros on Twitter. :P Though I did not know about Google's auto-replacement - that's a pretty strong argument in favor of the renaming (though I do not get the prompt or replacement, myself).

Comment: It's not a prompt like "Did you mean" or "Searching instead for": unless you do a verbatim search, Google will just expand it silently. You can tell by what words are bolded in search results, and also by the results being identical to a search for "magic the gathering online". Another data point: we rank first for "[mtgo effective card collection](http://google.com/search?q=mtgo+effective+card+collection)" despite "MTGO" not appearing at all in [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/79012/3389).

Comment: @MarkTrapp Your edit summarily covers my only real concern to the idea - not that the concern stopped me from upvoting it to begin with. :)

Answer (score 2):

Given that the tag has remained [mtg-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-online) for many years and that this appears to be the official name of the game (even though WOTC itself colloquially refers to the game as '*Magic Online*' in promos, updates etc), the tag was renamed to [magic-the-gathering-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-online) as per [this meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12868/28182).

However, I have added additional synonyms to the [magic-the-gathering-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-online) tag to address the concerns noted above. They are as follows:

- [mtg-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-online), [mtgo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtgo), [magic-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-online) → [magic-the-gathering-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-online)

If anyone has any other tag synonym suggestions or wishes to push the case for [magic-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-online) to be the primary tag further, let me know :)

Comment: I had thought that the official name of the game was *Magic: The Gathering Online*, since [that's what Wikipedia calls it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering_Online). Although it does say that it was originally released as *Magic Online*.

Comment: @Thunderforge - Yeah, I mean *"Magic The Gathering: Online"* appears to be correct today, even if it was "Magic Online" in the past and still referred to as such colloquially. I did research it before the rename to make sure it was the correct option :)