# Rename [mtg-*] → [magic-the-gathering-*]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

The tag for the games related to *[Magic: The Gathering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering)* should be renamed as follows, thanks to the 35 character tag limit:

- [mtg-duels-of-planeswalker](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-duels-of-planeswalker) → [mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers)
- [magic-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-2012) → [mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2012) (with synonym [magic-duels-planeswalkers-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-duels-planeswalkers-2012))*
- [magic-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-2013) → [mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013) (with synonym [magic-duels-planeswalkers-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-duels-planeswalkers-2013))*
- [magic-2014](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-2014) → [mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014) (with synonym [magic-duels-planeswalkers-2014](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-duels-planeswalkers-2014))*
- [magic-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-2015) → [mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2015) (with synonym [magic-duels-planeswalkers-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-duels-planeswalkers-2015))*
- [mtg-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-online) → [magic-the-gathering-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-online)
- [mtg-puzzle-quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-puzzle-quest) → [magic-the-gathering-puzzle-quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-puzzle-quest)
- [mtg-tactics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-tactics) → [magic-the-gathering-tactics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-tactics)

* Note that the *Duels of the Planeswalkers* series was previously changed to have `magic-` as its prefix instead of `mtg-` due to SEO concerns with the `dotp` abbreviation (see [Tag synonym request: [mtg-dotp-2012] and [magic-2012]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2437/47878)). However, I don't know if that's still a concern since we now can spell out `duels-of-the-planeswalkers`. I would be okay flipping them if it was.

For reference, there was also the old meta request [Tag rename request: [mtg-online] → [magic-online]](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5189/47878)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Done**. Here are the final results (in the form [synonym-1](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonym-1), [synonym-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonym-2)... [synonym-n](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synonym-n) → [master-tag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master-tag)):

- [magic-dotp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-dotp), [mtg-dotp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-dotp), [magic-the-gathering-dotp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-dotp), [magic-duels-planeswalkers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-duels-planeswalkers) → [mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers)
- [magic-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-2012), [mtg-dotp-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-dotp-2012), [magic-the-gathering-dotp-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-dotp-2012), [magic-duels-planeswalkers-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-duels-planeswalkers-2012) → [mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2012](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2012)
- [magic-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-2013), [mtg-dotp-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-dotp-2013), [magic-the-gathering-dotp-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-dotp-2013), [magic-duels-planeswalkers-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-duels-planeswalkers-2013) → [mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013)
- [magic-2014](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-2014), [mtg-dotp-2014](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-dotp-2014), [magic-the-gathering-dotp-2014](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-dotp-2014), [magic-duels-planeswalkers-2014](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-duels-planeswalkers-2014) → [mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2014)
- [magic-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-2015), [mtg-dotp-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-dotp-2015), [magic-the-gathering-dotp-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-dotp-2015), [magic-duels-planeswalkers-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-duels-planeswalkers-2015) → [mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2015](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2015)

Note that I removed the '*Duels of Planeswalker*' synonym entirely, I couldn't find any evidence of the name being shortened in this manner by the wider community, this was simply a hangover of Arqade's 25 char tag limit.

These renames were also actioned:

- [mtg-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-online) → [magic-the-gathering-online](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-online)
- [mtg-puzzle-quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-puzzle-quest) → [magic-the-gathering-puzzle-quest](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-puzzle-quest)
- [mtg-tactics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-tactics) → [magic-the-gathering-tactics](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-the-gathering-tactics)

Comment: @Thunderforge the tag was actually 'Planeswalker' not 'Planeswalkers'

Comment: Looks like I added an `s` when I was correcting the `Plainswalker` typo. Plains are only one of the six basic land types in Magic!

Comment: All good, thanks for the fix regardless :)

Comment: And thanks again for doing this thankless task!